# How to derive latent heat from the degrees of freedom in an equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I am having some trouble solving a question on statistical mechanics, any help?

Q: A certain material vaporizes from the liquid phase at 700 K. In both phases,
the molecules have three degrees of freedom. If u0 in the liquid phase is
−0.12 eV, what is the latent heat of vaporization in joules per mole?

Comment: Three *intrinsic* degrees of freedom (i.e. 6 including position)? What is 'u0'? The enthalpy per molecule? And what ideas have you had yourself?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).